# Switch (show one, hide the others) between jsson image sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

I need to create an image slider with thumbnails.

I've used [jssor silder](http://www.jssor.com/index.html) which is working fine.

The problem is I want to show a different set of images under different ids.

For example when any one of the years (2013,2014,2015) is clicked I need to show the country names under it; and when any country is clicked it should show the associated image slider.

The problem is the country names fade away when clicked.

How can I make them remain visible?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zx342nz4/)

---

```
  <p>2015</p>
</a>

<div id="list1" class="alist" style="display:none;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"  onclick="toggle_visibility('list');">
  <p>India </p>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('weed');">
  <p>U.S </p>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('daba');">
  <p>japan </p>
</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('list2');">
  <p>2014</p>
</a>
<div id="list2" class="alist" style="display:none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>###
```

Comment: There is no element with ID of `weed` or `daba` in your code and `getElementById` returns `null`.  Where are the _associated_ elements? The markup is very confusing and lacks any coherent structure.

Comment: Sorry ! New to stack overflow and coding ...

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/os1nourp/

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var thelist = document.getElementsByClassName("alist");

        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block') {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            e.style.display = 'block';
        }

    }
```

Is this what you are trying to do? Just remove the script that is closing other list.

Comment: Thanks ! you have showed me some way but still a prob when I click 2014 its again showing 2015 's div also ..